# Google analytics experiment SEO friendly url

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

Just trying to make a Test A/B experiment with google analytics content experiment. I manage an ecommerce site and I use a SEO-friendly style URL, the products could have different categories as you can see.

```
www.store.net/product/bedroom/bed/11
www.store.net/product/bedroom/bed/21
www.store.net/product/perfum/40
www.store.net/product/perfum/88
www.store.net/product/bedroom/furniture/mirror/5
www.store.net/product/bedroom/furniture/mirror/15
```

My product page for all is www.store.net/product.aspx?id=$1

This is my Original URL: www.store.net/product.aspx?id=$1
and Variation: &test=1

But...is not working....

Any ideas how could I do a test with SEO friendly URL?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'is not working', what do you mean?

Comment: For example if I go to this page www.store.net/product/perfum/40 will have to redirect to my variation with the param test=1.

Comment: I think is because I access to the page by the SEO friendly and not by in my case www.store.net/product.aspx?id=$1